# Use filter function to remove rows before certain date with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I want to subset a dataframe without rows that contain a certain value: `"Twitter for iPhone"` before a certain date. Here's my code:

```
library(dplyr)

all_trump_tweets %>%
  filter(created_at < "2017-03-25",
         source != "Twitter for iPhone")
```

Now this filters out the dates after `"2017-02-25"`. I actualy want to 'unfilter' so I still use above filter but **with** the dates after `"2017-03-25"` returned as well. Dataframe goes untill current date "2017-12-13".

something like this:

```
all_trump_tweets %>% 
filter(ifelse(created_at < "2017-03-25", source != "Twitter for iPhone"))
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: Try to apply your filters one after the other to understand better where the issue comes from. The above filter will give you dates before "2017-03-25" AND source different than "Twitter for iPhone". If the dates between "2017-02-25" and "2017-03-25" are filtered out that could mean only that they have source = "Twitter for iPhone".

Comment: Ah yes, what I want to do is: only filter out rows with value `"Twitter for iPhone"` if they exist before `"2017-03-25"` after that date there are only rows with iPhone values but I want to keep them! something like this `all_trump_tweets %>% filter(ifelse(created_at < "2017-03-25", source != "Twitter for iPhone"))`

Comment: Try this: `filter((created_at < "2017-03-25" & source != "Twitter for iPhone") | created_at >= "2017-03-25")`.

Comment: Wow thanks that worked!

Comment: You simply care about the `source` values ONLY when the date is before 2017-03-25. So for dates after that day you can return everything.